# Does Rugged Support .gitattributes?

Tags: git, rugged

If so, can someone point me at how to make use of them? I know that libgit2 supports them from [this](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/516), but I'm not having any luck in my research regarding support within Rugged.

Comment: Since Rugged is a language binding for libgit2, it supports as much (or as little) of `.gitattributes` as libgit2 does.  Most things (text/binary, etc) are supported.  Some things (pluggable filters, for example) are not supported in libgit2.  Is there a particular attribute that you're interested in?

Comment: If I made a .gitattributes file removing the diff ability from PDFs, for example, would Rugged no longer give me diffs for PDFs?

Comment: The additions to libgit2 that I mentioned appeared to only support the querying of .gitattributes, not using them with regular operations. But then again, I'm not very familiar with either libgit2 or Rugged-- I'm just trying to learn more.